# Most efficent way to code branches in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Say I have a Javascript array which contains numbers between 0 and 5. Each of the numbers is really an instruction to call a specific function. For example:

```
var array = [lots of data];

for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  if(i == 0){ function0(); };
  if(i == 1){ function1(); };
  if(i == 2){ function2(); };
  if(i == 3){ function3(); };
  if(i == 4){ function4(); };
  if(i == 5){ function5(); };
}
```

This seems like an awful lot of [branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) and unnecessary checks.  What would be a more performance minded way to call the function?

I've thought about dynamically creating the function names using [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp), but isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the functions in the array;

```
var array = [function0, function1, ..., functionN];
```

and then just call the functions on each iteration:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  array[i]();
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you I think the answer is the simplest most readable way to go! I knew there was an obvious easy way I just overlooked

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Object` as a map, or use the `switch` statement. The former is demonstrated below.

```
const functionMap = {
    0: function0,
    1: function1,
    2: function2
};

array.foreach(i => functionMap[i]());
```

Alternatively, if you can know the name of the function based off of `i`, you can call it from the parent scope, e.g.

```
window[`function${i}`]()
```

However, strictly speaking, manually coding in the `if` statements (or using a `switch`) may be the most performant. I doubt there will be a significant performance difference between any of them.

Comment: .foreach() would be more appropriate than .map() here

Comment: The 2 options you posted are great examples how I've overlooked the most simple of things! I looked up how switch works on the backend, and it's similar to if-than, however the functionMap makes a type of dictionary Hash table to compare id's to keys, making it significantly faster. However after reading all the answers I think the fastest way is to store the function in an array and access the index.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be called as strings, so `window['function' + i]()` would work, and call a function. This can be very dynamic.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

function function0() { console.log('Function 0') }
function function1() { console.log('Function 1') }
function function2() { console.log('Function 2') }

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (typeof window['function' + i] == 'function') {
    window['function' + i]()
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this is generally not good practice, accessing global variables by string keys is difficult to track / debug & the usage of each function is not as immediately obvious.